# VSCode doesn't recognize python interpreter

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am on arch linux, and for some reason VSCode doesn't find the python interpreter.

I have tried to set the python interpreter path to to be right (/bin/python3), and if I actually run a file then it works, but the python extension says I need to download python before using the extension and the auto complete doesnt work. Any Ideas? Any ways to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution with [vscode-insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/). The current vscode python extension is already move on to rely on jupyter, another extension available only on vscode insiders.

Plus the vsc insiders logo looks cool..

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issues, downgrading to Electron9.3.3-1 solved the issue for me while waiting for a potential fix.

Source: [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14721#issuecomment-729875758)